# Get fields name into a Javascript loop

Tags: visualforce, standard-objects, fields, loop

I do a loop on random fields of `Attachment` object and I try to get the label of fields.

```
// arr is an array with some random fields of Attachment object
for (var i=0, i<arr.length; i++) {
    var myLabel = {!$ObjectType.Attachment.fields[arr[i]].label};
}
```

I tried this but this code doesn't work !

Comment: Where are you using those labels?

Comment: In some <outputText>. But I'm wondering if it's possible in JavaScript ? Maybe not, but maybe it's possible in Apex classes ?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the example of <apex:outputText> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the accepted answer of another question I posted that solved my problem : [Get field label without doing a loop](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33308/get-field-label-without-doing-a-loop)