# Get field label without doing a loop

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, standard-objects, fields, loop

Is there a way to get the label of a field without doing a loop on all object fields like this :

```
Map<String, SobjectField> fieldMap = Account.getsObjectType().getDescribe().Fields.getMap(); 
for(String f :  fieldMap.keySet())
System.debug(fieldMap.get(f).getDescribe().getLabel());
```

Something like this :

```
String label = Account.getField('myFieldName').getLabel();
```

Comment: Do you intend to you use it in a visualforce page?

Comment: Yes that's the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this in VisualForce you can use the following pattern:

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.['MyField__c'].Label}
```

`Account` can also be replaced by `['Account']` in the above line

If you have a List of field names that you need to iterate over then you can use the [apex:repeat](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm) tag. See the example below

```
<apex:repeat value="{! fieldNames}" var="fieldName"> 
    <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.[fieldName].Label}">
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Apex code, if you want the label of a field that you know about at compile time you can directly use the SObjectField reference (`Account.BillingCity` in this case but can be your custom fields too) and get the describe information from that:

```
String label = Account.BillingCity.getDescribe().getLabel();
```

But if you only know the field name at runtime, there is a map available on the fields collection that you can use without a loop. For example:

```
String label = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('BillingCity').getDescribe().getLabel();
```

**PS** Just noticed the comment that you want to do this in Visualforce not Apex. So you should follow BarCotter's approach.

Comment: This can also be done directly in VisualForce using this pattern: `{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.['BillingCity'].Label}`

Comment: @BarCotter : I don't know the name of the field. It's on a loop so can I do something like : `{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.[myLoop[i]].Label}` where `myLoop[i]` represent an Account field ?

Comment: I have added an answer with the details

Answer (score 0):

then use this :

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label}
```

Where Name is you field

Comment: I see this but the problem is that I have a random Account fields list. I have to loop on all fields and get the field label.
I already ask about it (in Javascript) : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33124/get-fields-name-into-a-javascript-loop

Comment: Ah, then in this case I don't think that you have another choice than what you already did in you question.

Comment: You speak about the loop ?

Comment: Yes.   I don't know about another way to get dynamically fields and labels for an SObject, and the simplest way as @Keith C told you. if you already knew the field name.